# JTextPane line wrapping issue

Tags: java, line, jtextpane, word-wrap

I have issue with line wrapping in JTextPane. It is hard to explain it, so i make a video with this problem (http://youtu.be/s35QbwEgtvk).

There is my SSCCE:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(350, 300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
pane.insertIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("images.jpg"))));

frame.add(pane);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Any idea, how can I solve this issue? I want to image will act like word.

Comment: I think this is probably caused by the way JTextPane handles text and images. JTextPane can be configured to use custom styles though so you might be able to fix your problem using that.

Helpfull links: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html  

API
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#getLogicalStyle()

Comment: I know this is not the expected answer, but if you don't want to loose your time, you can just insert/remove a character after typing a space. This way, you will force the text pane to update its interpretation of the position of your previous word. Otherwise, did you try to just invalidate the view of the previous character ?